# Oracle Apex - How Show Image in a Dynamic List

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created dynamic list for sub-menu page,now i want to show image for each list entry

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A nice feature is to use Apex Font Awesome icons.

Here's an example of a dynamic list query, based on Scott's DEPT table:

```
select 
  null lvl,
  dname,
  '#' target,
  null is_current,
  case when deptno = 10 then 'fa-thumbs-o-up' 
       when deptno = 20 then 'fa-thumbs-o-down'
  end icon
from dept 
order by deptno
```

When you add the list to the page (as a region), navigate to its "Attributes" and modify template options by setting the "Display icons" property to "For all items".

Once you run the page, you'll see a *thumb up* icon by department 10 and *thumb down* for department 20.

List of all available icons is [here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=42:icons).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in Example 1 in the SQL page of the Create List wizard:

```
Example 1:
SELECT null, 
       ENAME label, 
       null target, 
       'YES' is_current, 
       '#APP_IMAGES#del.gif' image, -- <-- HERE
       'width="20" height="20"' image_attrib, 
       ENAME image_alt
FROM  emp 
ORDER BY ename
```

Answer (score 0):

first use query like below:

```
select 
  1 level,
  dname label,
  '#' target,
  null is_current,
  'IMAGE'||img_name image
from dept 
order by deptno
```

with this query img_name set as class for each card. after that use this javascript code on page load:

```
var spns = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i = 0; i < spns.length; i++) {                        
 if (spns[i].className.includes('-IMAGE')) { 

   spns[i].style.backgroundImage = "url(#IMAGE_PREFIX#"+spns[i].className.substring(5)+")";

  $('.'+spns[i].className.substring(5)).css("background-size", "cover");
     }    
  }
```

for this background image url should exist images on ords server.
good luck